# One query instead of two?

Tags: php, mysql

Here I'm making two queries with PHP. Is there something more simple? One query instead of two?

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questionstable WHERE id=$id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$category = $row['category'];
$main = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM categorytable WHERE id=$category");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT       questionstable.*, categorytable.name
FROM         questionstable
  INNER JOIN categorytable
  ON         categorytable.id = questionstable.category
WHERE        questionstable.id=$id
```

As an aside, assuming your `questionstable.id` is numeric, you could use `$id = (int)$_GET["id"]` and save some writing. (It's also probably a safer bet. Just because it's escaped doesn't mean it's *completely* safe--especially when it's not within quotes [gives you a LOT of options for SQL injection]. ;-))

Comment: it should be WHERE questionstable.id=$id.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT name 
FROM categorytable 
WHERE id = (
              SELECT category 
              FROM questionstable 
              WHERE id = $id
           )
```

Comment: but then i cannot use questionstable's rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$main = mysql_query("SELECT c.name FROM categorytable c inner join questionstable q on c.category = q.category WHERE q.id = $id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use inner join use left join instead, **it won't return any result if the category is not found**

```
SELECT    questionstable.*, categorytable.name
FROM      questionstable
LEFT JOIN categorytable
ON         categorytable.id = questionstable.category
WHERE      id=$id
```